# Checking parenthesis of racket function

Tags: scheme, racket

> I'm trying to make a function that takes a non-empty string representing a Racket function and an index of that string. If the index refers to a right parenthesis, then the index of the matching left parentheses is returned. Else false.

```
> (find-paren "(if (zero? x) (* 2 x) x)" 11)
false
> (find-paren "(if (zero? x) (* 2 x) x)" 12)
4
> (find-paren "(+ (* 2 (- 5 3)) (/ (+ 4 2) 3))" 14)
8
> (find-paren "(+ (* 2 (- 5 3)) (/ (+ 4 2) 3))" 15)
3
> (find-paren "(+ (* 2 (- 5 3)) (/ (+ 4 2) 3))" 30)
0
```

And I'm trying to do this the quickest way possible so no explode, substring, string->list, string-ith.` I've been stuck on this problem for almost an hour now. If the string was symetric then my function would work:

```
(define (find-paren expr i)
  (cond [(not (equal? #\) (string-ref expr i))) false]
        [else (- (string-length expr) i)]))
```

But it's not symmetric. I also created a function that counts how many times a character appears in a string, but I'm not sure if it would help that much:

```
(define (char-count c s)
  (local [(define (loop i count)
            (cond
              [(negative? i) count]
              [(char=? c (string-ref s i))
               (loop (sub1 i) (add1 count))]
              [else
               (loop (sub1 i) count)]))]
    (loop (sub1 (string-length s)) 0)))
```

Any help would be great in ISL+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are to work with actual Racket expression, you will sooner rather than later need to turn the string representation into a list of tokens using a lexer.

The program below shows how to find pairs of matching left and right parentheses. 
Given that list, it is easy to find the left parenthesis that match a given right parenthesis.

If you a solution that works directly on the string representation, you need to mimick the algorithm in `pair-parens-loop`.

```
; a TOKEN consists of a lexeme (a 'left, 'right or a char)
; and the position from which the lexeme was read.
(define-struct token (lexeme pos))

; left? and right? checks whether the token was a left or right parenthesis respectively.
(define (left? t)  (eq? (token-char t) 'left))
(define (right? t) (eq? (token-char t) 'right))

; lex : string -> list-of-tokens
;   lex the whole string
(define (lex s)
  (lex-loop s 0))

; lex-loop : string natural -> list-of-tokens
;   lex-loop the part of the string that begins with position p
(define (lex-loop s p)
  (cond
    [(= p (string-length s))        '()]
    [(char=? (string-ref s p) #\()  (cons (make-token 'left p)  (lex-loop s (+ p 1)))]
    [(char=? (string-ref s p) #\))  (cons (make-token 'right p) (lex-loop s (+ p 1)))]
    [else                           (lex-loop s (+ p 1))]))

; pair-parens : list-of-tokens -> list-of-list-of-tokens
;   return a list of mathcing left/right tokens
(define (pair-parens ts)
  (pair-parens-loop ts '() '()))

(define (pair-parens-loop ts pending found)
  (cond
    [(empty? ts) found]
    [(left?  (first ts))
     (pair-parens-loop (rest ts) (cons (first ts) pending) found)]
    [(right? (first ts))
     (pair-parens-loop (rest ts) (rest pending) (cons (list (first pending) (first ts)) found))]
    [else (error)]))


;;;
;;; EXAMPLE
;;;

> (lex "(if (zero? x) (* 2 x) x)")
(list
 (make-token 'left 0)
 (make-token 'left 4)
 (make-token 'right 12)
 (make-token 'left 14)
 (make-token 'right 20)
 (make-token 'right 23))


> (pair-parens (lex "(if (zero? x) (* 2 x) x)"))
(list
 (list (make-token 'left 0) (make-token 'right 23))
 (list (make-token 'left 14) (make-token 'right 20))
 (list (make-token 'left 4) (make-token 'right 12)))
```

Comment: Scroll down to see the output.

Comment: This is really good and works well. Of course I'm trying to use pair-parens-loop with string instead of lists, but I'm a bit stuck on that. You wouldn't use tokens so how would you find and call each value?

Comment: In the string version of `pair-parens-loop` the tokens will be characters. The `ts` variable is simply your input string. The `pending` becomes an index into the string. `found` will be a list of (list character index). Also `pair-paren-loop` should test and skip characters other than ( and ) by looping with the pending index incremented by one (the token version discarded everything but parentheses).

Comment: Yes, but the function would still be doing multiple passes, once to make the list of 'left and 'right and another to pair them. Is there a way to do it in a single pass?

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is: Is there a way to use a function like foldl to first find the right parenthesis at the index you specified and if it is there then continue down the list to find the left parenthesis it matches with.

Comment: You can test for #\\( and #\\) instead of turning them into 'left and 'right first.

Comment: If you tested for only the Char and Char then you wouldn't be able to compare the index location. And if you tested for only index location then you wouldn't be able to compare the Char

Comment: The function `pair-paren-loop` doesn't test the index - but when it puts something onto `pending` or `found` you need need to make a token with the char and the index.